# Get Current System Time

Tags: android, datetime

How to get Current System's Time and Date without using `Calender.getInstance()`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try

```
Date d = new Date();
CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy ", d.getTime());
```

You can edit the format string as you like..

Comment: Hi Tushar .I need DateTime in this formate(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss)

Comment: you can use it only use 'hh' instead of 'HH'

Comment: It not worked for me. `The method format(Date) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (String, long)`

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
//-------- Don't know whether this will work on android or not.
long dtMili = System.currentTimeMillis();
Date dt = new Date(dtMili);
```

or

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Comment: But it return only Date like as 2011-02-23 but i also need DateTime like as "2011-02-23 16:38:45"

Comment: @CapDroid: for that use `DateFormat` class.

Answer (score 2):

Constructing a new [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) will give the current date. thereafter you can use date.setTime( System.currentTimeMillis() ) to update that object

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
  DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
  df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));

  df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```